# HTML5 Video tag issues on Iphone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, video, html5-video

Hello I am very new to HTML5 video and I'm having a problem with videos NOT playing on my iPhone 4 (running iOS 6.1.2) when using the HTML5 video tag.

The video runs fine on a computer with Google Chrome. The browser I am using Safari on the iPhone.

I have tried using multiple file formats together such as .OGG .webM and h264 MP4. 
Something that is really confusing me however is that I have tried playing a HTML5 video at the bottom of this [article](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) on my iPhone and it still does not work.

I thought this blog would be the example to follow for HTML5 video, but now I really can't work out what is going wrong. I also tried it on another iPhone4 and it did not work.

Does anyone know what is going on here or what the problem is with HTML5 video on the iPhone? Could someone help me with a good way to display video that is not using something like Youtube but more along the lines of HTML5?

Thank you!!

Comment: html5 video is a total disaster. the w3c standardized the tag, but didn't have the guts (or maybe political muscle) to standardize any particular video codec(s), so there's no standard format that all devices will play. microsoft browsers prefer their .wmv stuff, google's pushing vp8, apple's doing .mp4, blah blah blah.

Comment: Hmm thats a shame, so if not HTML5 for IOS web video, what do I do? And again I want to mention I want to avoid embedding from youtube etc. :)

Comment: you can use html5 video no problem, you just have to serve up a format the ios supports.

Comment: So this is the trouble I am having, I have used mp4 which I think is the correct one. The video just simply wont run.

Comment: Made a discovery on this topic which solved my problem. I was testing the video on my phone without using WIFI or 3G, it was GPRS, very slow connection. The video was not playing on the slow connection. I then tried it on a 3g connection at it worked. So for some reason bandwidth effected it a great deal. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you

We need three formats of HTML5 to be able to work on all browsers including mobiles.

1. mp4 encoded with H.264
2. webm
3. ogv

Encoding video using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -codec:v libx264 -profile:v high -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 500k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:480 -threads 0 -codec:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

detail here http://skillrow.com/html5-video-for-all-browsers/